# Discrete Approximation to Gaussian smoothing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, convolution, smoothing

I am trying to find a discrete approximation to the Gaussian smoothing operation, as shown in the link :

http://bit.ly/1cSgkwt

**G** is some **discrete** smoothing kernel, a Gaussian in this case and ***** is the convolution operation. Basically, I want to apply a smoothing kernel to each pixel in the image. I am doing this in MATLAB and using the following code to create the matrix **G**, which is naive and hence painfully slow :

```
z = rgb2gray(imread('train_02463_1.bmp'));
im_sz = size(z);
ksize = 5;

% Gaussian kernel of size ksize*ksize
gw_mat = g_sigma(1,2*ksize+1)'*g_sigma(1,2*ksize+1);

G = sparse(length(ksize+1:im_sz(1)-ksize),prod(im_sz));
for i = ksize+1:im_sz(1)-ksize
    for j = ksize+1:im_sz(2)-ksize

    [x,y] = meshgrid(i-ksize:i+ksize,j-ksize:j+ksize);
    row_num = sub2ind(im_sz,i,j);
    colnums = sub2ind(im_sz,x,y);
    G(row_num,colnums(:)) = gw_mat(:)';

    end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

**EDIT**: I should apologize for not complete specifying the problem. Most of the answers below are valid ones, but the issue here is the above approximation is part of a optimization objective where the variable is **z**. The whole problem looks something like this :

http://goo.gl/rEE02y

Thus, I have to pre-generate a matrix **G** which approximates a smoothing function in order to feed this objective to a solver. I am using **cvx**, if that helps.

Comment: Why not just use `conv2` (or one of its more helpful variants like `imfilter`)?

Comment: Please refer to the EDIT. Using external functions is not possible here since I am feeding this into a solver, so I require to generate a matrix which does smoothing over the entire vector.

Comment: Did you call your matrix G because it is ginormous? It is 4*ksize^2=100 times larger than your image and then you fill it up in 2 loops that are notoriously slow in Matlab. Which brings a question about what your solver does that it requires such a huge thing? If you just look for a speed up do it with meshgrid() by shifting a pre-generated one rather than generating it all the time. Just print it out to see how to shift.

Answer (score 1):

Typically people do it by applying two 1D Gaussian functions sequentially instead of one 2D function (idea of separable filters). You can approximate 1D horizontal Gaussian pretty fast, apply it to each pixel, save result in temp, and then apply a vertical Gaussian to temp. The expected speed up is quite significant: O(ksize*ksize) -> O(ksize+ksize)

Comment: Agreed. If you notice my code, I generate the 2D gaussian kernel by taking the outer product of two 1D Gaussians. I have updated the question though, which should have been done earlier. Sorry about that.

Comment: Creating a 2D Gaussian kernel from two 1D Gaussians is not the same as using separable filters.
You should just filter it with 1D Gaussian in one direction and then filter the result with another 1D Gaussian in the other direction. This will lead to the same result for significantly lower computational price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use approximate Gaussian smoothing via box filters, e.g see [`integgaussfilt.m`](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/#integral):

> This function approximates Gaussian filtering by repeatedly applying
>   averaging filters.  The averaging is performed via [integral images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) which
>   results in a fixed and very low computational cost that is independent of
>   the Gaussian size.

Comment: The cost is low if the filtering is performed at multiple kernel sizes  on the same image (i.e. if the cost of computing the integral image(s) can be amortized over several filtering operations). If however, you are filtering once at a fixed kernel size, going the integral image route is a net loser.

Comment: Calculation of box filter is faster than same with "integral image", and can be calculated in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to apply Spatially Invariant Filter on an image using MATLAB would be using [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html).
`imfilter` will automatically notice "Seperable" Kernel and will apply it in 2 steps (Vertically / Horizontally).

For creating some known and useful kernels you may look at [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html).